# Как заменить элементы в списке, чтобы получить определенный список?

Tags: python, строки, list, replace

Всем привет. Возникла необходимость создать такую функцию, которая будет делать из имеющегося списка целевой список, используя только определенные замены. Предположим, дан список **have**, из него нужно сделать список **need**, используя только замены из словаря **trade**, где **ключ** соответствует букве/буквам из **have**, а **значение** букве/буквам из **need**. Замены работают только в одну сторону, то есть можно поменять ключ на значение, но не наоборот. Если это сделать невозможно с данными списками **have**, **need** или **trade**, то программа должна об этом сообщить. В конце добавил две строчки, которые делают из списков строки, поскольку в **trade** есть замены нескольких букв на несколько.

UPD Никакого готового алгоритма нет, нужно просто проверить возможность "превратить" **have** в **need**. Если возможно, то вывести какими шагами из **trade** это было сделано, если нет, то сообщить, что это невозможно.

```
have = ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'v', 'r', 'r']
need = ['b', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'g', 'g', 'v', 'v', 'v', 'v', 'v', 'v', 'v', 'v', 'r', 'r']
trade = {'rr':'bb', 'prr':'ggv', 'gp':'rrr', 'gg':'rr',
    'bbb':'p', 'bbb':'g', 'bbb':'v', 'bbb':'r',
    'ppp':'b', 'ppp':'g', 'ppp':'v', 'ppp':'r',
    'ggg':'p', 'ggg':'b', 'ggg':'v', 'ggg':'r',
    'vvv':'p', 'vvv':'g', 'vvv':'b', 'vvv':'r',
    'rrr':'p', 'rrr':'g', 'rrr':'v', 'rrr':'b'}
have_str_srtd = ''.join(sorted(have))
need_str_srtd = ''.join(sorted(need))
```

Comment: А можно точнее? Например, как из последовательности первых девяти "b" в вашем списке have получилось последовательность "bpppp" в списке need? Почему тут первая буква никак не была обработана? Или - почему использовалась подстановка "bbb" -> 'p', но ни разу не использовалась подстановки "bbb" -> "g" или bbb" -> "r". Или - почему не сработала последняя подстановка "rr"->"b".  Видно, что проведенные вами замены не соответствуют вашему описанию. Согласуйте их, а ещё лучше -  опишите подробно особенности вашего алгоритма подстановки.

Comment: В том и дело, что никакого алгоритма нет, нужно просто проверить возможность "превратить" have в need. Если возможно, то вывести какими шагами из trade это было сделано, если нет, то сообщить, что это невозможно.

Comment: Так что проверять? Первые три символа have_str_srtd  не соответствуют первому символу need_str_srtd.  Значит получить вторую строку из первой невозможно.